# Why does my program exit after scanf("%i", x);, where x is int x;

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

My code stops taking input after the second score and ends execution. I can't think of any reason why it might be doing that
below code takes first and second score inputs from me, skips the third, and ends execution without going further.

This below C code stops taking input after the second and exits. It accepts the first and second input, skips the third, and exits.

How do I resolve this error? Below is my provided code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int scores[3];
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    printf("first score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", x);
    scores[0] = x;
    printf("second score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", y);
    scores[1] = y;
    printf("third score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", z);
    scores[2] = z;
    printf("average is %f\n", (scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2])/(float)3);
}
```

Comment: Strong recommendation: do not ignore the return codes. The users who are not trying to deliberately break your program for fun and profit are morons who hit the wrong keys and flood your program's input with typos. Never trust a user. Every potential error that you do not intercept and handle is a bug you'll eventually have to find and fix the hard way.

Comment: `scanf` needs a pointer to store the value, like `&x` and `&y`.

Comment: And sadly integers look enough like pointers that the code compiles. But if you ask it nicely, the compiler may be able to tell you what's wrong. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/xjP6M7aW5

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. (With gcc, you could use `-Wall -Werror -pedantic -Werror`.) It would have caught this error.

Comment: @Vazhun, In general, avoid `float` and use `double`: `(scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2])/(float)3` --> `(scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2])/3.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the address of a variable to `scanf` in order for it to work correctly. As a pointer is an integer type, passing an integer instead of a pointer can "work" but leads to undefined behaviour. Compiling with warnings on should tell you this. If I compile your code with `-Wall -Wextra` I see several, including warnings about the argument type passed to `scanf`.

If I further add `-Werror` then warnings get treated as errors and I have to fix this before my code will compile into something I can run. *Suggestion: fix the first error/warning **first** and then recompile.*

```
test.c:9:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%i", x);
           ~~   ^
test.c:12:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%i", y);
           ~~   ^
test.c:15:17: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    scanf("%i", z);
           ~~   ^
test.c:9:17: warning: variable 'x' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%i", x);
                ^
test.c:5:10: note: initialize the variable 'x' to silence this warning
    int x;
         ^
          = 0
test.c:12:17: warning: variable 'y' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%i", y);
                ^
test.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'y' to silence this warning
    int y;
         ^
          = 0
test.c:15:17: warning: variable 'z' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%i", z);
                ^
test.c:7:10: note: initialize the variable 'z' to silence this warning
    int z;
         ^
          = 0
6 warnings generated.
```

Correcting that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int scores[3];
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    printf("first score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    scores[0] = x;
    printf("second score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &y);
    scores[1] = y;
    printf("third score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &z);
    scores[2] = z;
    printf("average is %f\n", (scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2])/(float)3);
}
```

Of course, `x`, `y`, and `z` are redundant.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int scores[3];

    printf("first score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &scores[0]);

    printf("second score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &scores[1]);

    printf("third score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &scores[2]);

    printf("average is %f\n", (scores[0]+scores[1]+scores[2])/(float)3);
}
```

You should be checking the `scanf` returns `1` each time, indicating it has successfully read one value. If not, you should take some action, as otherwise you are working with uninitialized data, meaning your program could print *anything*.

Further, when you are dealing with arrays, repeating your code to read multiple values is a waste. Use a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 3

int main(void)
{
    int scores[ARR_SIZE];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Score %d is:\n", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &scores[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    int sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        sum += scores[i];
    }

    printf("Average is %f\n", sum/(float)ARR_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: only follow up question I would ask is why did it take 2 inputs and skip the third, as I can see none of the scanf had address and just had the variable.

Comment: Undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the program even compiles without warnings or error.

`scanf` takes a pointer to `int` as its second argument. So it should read:

```
scanf("%i", &x);
```

and similarly for y and z.

Comment: Sadly GCC doesn't warn  about any of this stuff unless you ask for it.  clang and Visual Studio's cl do, though. does

Answer (score -1):

The issue in your code is with the `scanf` function. The `scanf` function expects the address of the variables where it should store the input values, but you are passing the values directly.

Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int scores[3];
    int x, y, z;

    printf("first score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);
    scores[0] = x;

    printf("second score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &y);
    scores[1] = y;

    printf("third score is:\n");
    scanf("%i", &z);
    scores[2] = z;

    printf("average is %f\n", (scores[0] + scores[1] + scores[2]) / (float)3);

    return 0;
}
```

In this corrected code, the key change is in the `scanf` calls, where `&x`, `&y`, and `&z` are used to pass the addresses of `x`, `y`, and `z` to `scanf`, allowing it to store the user input in those variables.

I hope this resolves your issue. For any further assistance or doubts, you could comment below.